# Strip all html lines/code from string in python

Tags: python, email

Given the following string parsed from an email body...

```
s = "Keep all of this <h1>But remove this including the tags</h1> this is still good, but
    <p>there also might be new lines like this that need to be removed</p>

    <p> and even other lines like this all the way down here with whitespace after being  parsed from email that need to be removed.</p>

    But this is still okay."
```

How do I remove all the html code and lines from the string to simply return "Keep all of this this is still good But this is still okay." on one line? I've looked at bleach and lxml but they are simply just removing the html <> and returning what's inside, whereas I don't want any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use lxml to get all of the root element's text nodes:

```
import lxml.html

html = '''
    Keep all of this <h1>But remove this including the tags</h1> this is still good, but
    <p>there also might be new lines like this that need to be removed</p>

    <p> and even other lines like this all the way down here with whitespace after being  parsed from email that need to be removed.</p>

    But this is still okay.
'''

root = lxml.html.fromstring('<div>' + html + '</div>')
text = ' '.join(t.strip() for t in root.xpath('text()') if t.strip())
```

Seems to work fine:

```
>>> text
'Keep all of this this is still good, but But this is still okay.'
```

Comment: nice job, you actually read the question and realized OP wanted to remove some text as well as the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that requires no external packages:

```
import re
while '<' in s:
    s = re.sub('<.+?>.+?<.+?>', '', s)
```

Not very efficient, since it passes over the target string many times, but it should work. Note there must be absolutely no `<` or `>` characters on the string.

Answer (score 0):

This one?

```
import re
s = # Your string here

print re.sub('[\s\n]*<.+?>.+?<.+?>[\s\n]*', ' ', s)
```

Edit: Just made a few mods to @BoppreH answer albeit with an extra space.

Comment: this just removes the tags, not the text the OP wanted removed as well